# Geolocalização com html5

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho a necessidade de capturar a localização do usuário no momento em que ele abre a minha página. Ao realizar testes por meio de um button que chama a função getLocation() contendo os comandos para realizar a captura das informações que preciso, encontrei um problema ao visualizar que no momento em que acesso o site por um navegador móvel no android, ele só pede a permissão para coletar dados da localização se o gps do celular do usuário estiver ligado, caso o contrário ele não consegue executar minha função. O problema é que ninguém hoje em dia anda com a localização ativa devido ao alto consumo de bateria. Teria alguma maneira de eu conseguir ligar o gps da pessoa ou alguma outra maneira de pegar a localização no navegador pelo android?

Comment: Ligar o GPS sozinho é impossível. Você teria que avisar ao usuário que o GPS necessita ser ligado.
Veja nesse [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125922/check-if-user-devices-gps-is-on) se ajuda.

Comment: Opa, obrigado Douglas, vou aproveitar a ideia de um dos comentários do post que você colocou aqui, exibindo um alerta no callback de erro, é o jeito mesmo mas obrigado pela ajuda.